# How do I effectively process a largs gzipped file in dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

We have som batch jobs that process gzipped files that are ~10GB zipped and ~30GB unzipped.

Trying to process this, in java, takes an unreasonable amount of time and we are looking for how to do it more effective. If we use `TextIO` or the native java sdk for gcs to download the file it takes more than 8 hours to process, and the reason is ut can scale out for some reason. Most likely it won't split the file since it is gzipped.

If I unzipped the file and process the unzipped file the job take roughly 10 minute, so in the order of 100 times as fast.

I can totally understand that it might take some extra time to process a gzipped file, but 100 times as long time is too much.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that gzipped files are not splittable, so Dataflow has no way to parallelize reading each gzipped input file. Storing uncompressed in GCS is the best route if it's possible for you.

Regarding the 100x performance difference: how many worker VMs did your pipeline scale up to in the uncompressed vs compressed versions of your pipeline? If you have a job id we can look it up internally to investigate further.

Comment: I don't think it matters so much how many workers I had since the load isn't splittable. I tried to start the job with 30 workers, but since it can't split it automatically scales it down.

Comment: Would it be possible to have `TextIO` to unzip and write to a temporary folder before processing so it can parallelize the load. That is actually what we are trying to do at the moment.

Comment: Having TextIO first decompress and write to GCS would be similarly slow and wouldn't improve performance. Unless the same files are being read by multiple pipelines and thus the cost of decompression could be amortized across them.

Comment: If each input file is split into many records after reading, you can add a GroupByKey after splitting in order to for a reshuffle and allow downstream processing to execute in parallel.

Comment: Maybe, but there might be a lot of improvements that can be done to to `TextIO` to speed up the scenario with gzipped file. Some minor tests I've been doing yields the following: * processing zipped file, 8 hours. * processing unzipped file, 10 minutes. * Downloading file, 10 minutes. * Unzipping file, 5 minutes. * Uploading unzipped file: ~30 mintes. So all the steps of download, unzip, upload & process should give roughly 40-45 minutes. Which is much shorter than the 8 hours it takes today.

Comment: Ok, so you say I can use a "regular" `TextIO`and then do `GroupByKey` just to force it to split? Or how do you mean the split would take place?

Comment: Yes, after your transform logic splits the input file into many records, you can add a synthetic "GroupByKey" with unique keys (generated using random numbers, for example), and then a ParDo which re-expands the iterable. This is described as a "fusion break" here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion and the Reshuffle transform is one example: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.1.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.java

Comment: Thanks you so much! It seems like this brought up the processing speed to 150.000 lines/s instead of 6000 lines/s. I'm still unsure to why I don't get 600.000 as I got with unzipped though, maybe I used more workers?? Eitherway, this is an improvement we most likely can live with.

Comment: In an attempt to scale this further I tried to also apply fixedwindows, beause as it is now it seems like the job "stops" until everything has been grouped and then it continues. I was hoping that fixedwindows would start emitting data with the specified interval and thus allowing the rest of the pipeline to run. Is that possible?

Comment: If this is for a streaming pipeline, you can specify a window + trigger to limit how the elements are grouped-- using the `Reshuffle` transform will do this for you. If this is a batch pipeline, what you're seeing is how Dataflow schedules processing; completing upstream steps before moving on. Note that the "fusion break" will cause some additional I/O; for optimal performance it'd be best to read in uncompressed data.

Comment: this is batch, so I guess this is the best I can get. I noticed that playing around with how I group things had a performance impact. Going to uncompressed is on the roadmap.